# Probability of hitting the dart board in the second ring.

Tags: probability, contest-math

> There is a shooting event organised by the SBT youth Club to select
> the best candidate who will qualify to participate in Eklavya
> championship. The shooting board is designed by using $4$ concentric
> circles of radii $2$ inch, $3$ inch, $5$ inch and $9$ inch. What is
> the probability that the participant will shoot only in the second
> ring to qualify for Eklavya championship?

Total area = $81\pi $
Area of the second ring = $5\pi$

So shouldn't the probability will be = $\frac{5}{81}$

But this is not the right answer. The correct answer that has been given is $\frac{16}{81}$ and I am not able to get that how can this be the answer? What am I doing wrong? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What is the right answer?

Comment: The confusions seems to be about the definition of what second ring means. Is the right answer $1/9$?

Comment: @RishiSonthalia : Updated the question with the answer that has been given.

Comment: Dunno. Maybe it was meant to ask "third ring" (or the smallest is not counted as a ring because it is a disk). After all $16=5^2-3^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusion seems to be in the way *ring* is defined. The question should have made this more clear, in my opinion.

[image]

The red circle in the centre of the above dart board does not represent a *ring*. Only the green and blue regions are *rings.* Therefore, the second *ring* corresponds to the blue region.

Hence, the answer is

$$\frac{\pi \cdot (5^2 - 3^2)}{\pi \cdot 9^2} = \boxed{\frac{16}{81}}$$